# Macbook pro won't turn on after battery died

Tags: power, macbook-pro, macbook-pro-retina

My macbook pro retina was working perfectly fine up until last night. I put it in sleep mode at around 11% battery left thinking I'll charge it tomorrow.

Approx 12 hours later it won't turn on at all.

I plugged in the charger and let charge till the light went green but it's not turning on.

I've tried and smc reset but still no luck.

It doesn't have a battery pack.

Comment: What do you man it "doesn't have a battery pack?"  Can you clarify?  If you press and hold the power button for 5 seconds, then try again, does it boot?

Comment: It doesn't have a battery. I've held it in for ages. It seems to be dead

Comment: Still confused.  Does it *have* a battery in it that doesn't hold a charge or is there physically no battery?  If the latter, how can it have 11% charge?

Comment: There is no removable battery. There is an internal battery but no removable battery pack

Comment: What model Macbook Pro?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The SMC usually helps in situations like that, but you might try some of the other boot commands. I've had different ones fix various problems randomly.

- Hold <kbd>Shift</kbd> on boot - Safe mode
- <kbd>CMD</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd> - Verbose mode
- <kbd>CMD</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd> - Recovery mode
- <kbd>CMD</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd> - Reset PRAM

Start by holding the power button for 5 seconds to make sure it is fully off before each command.

I'd also connect a display to it and see if you get any feedback.